# Crontab Redhat 8: Crontab will not run an R script that works perfectly otherwise

Tags: r, linux, cron

I'm currently trying to run a R file every minute through crontab. The R file take in a file from the previous directory and inputs into a sub-directory. If I just ./script.R the command will run fine, read and output all the data 100% accurately. However, in crontab it will not even run. I have tried a sample crontab to test if it was my crontab not working first, I wrote

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "foobar" >> /home/a/t/test.log
```

This command would correctly send foobar to the log.
However when I did

```
* * * * * /home/a/t/script.R >> /home/a/t/test.log
```

I would get no results within the test.log, nor would I get results in the subdirectory it should store in after being ran. I also did the script another way to see if the * were causing issues

```
*/1 * * * * /home/a/t/script.R >> /home/a/t/test.log
```

This also did not give any results.
After some research what I can understand is that there is likely an issue with paths. So to try to counteract that I did a cd command along with the R command as such:

```
 */1 * * * *  cd /home/a/t/ && /home/a/t/script.R >> /home/a/t/test.log
```

Still, however, this has given 0 output. If I type
grep CRON /var/log/cron
I see cron trying to run the lines every minute, but again no output found anywhere, I dont think it is running and I can't understand why not.
Also in terms of path for the R script itself, within the R script I have the first line written something like

```
#!/bin/env Rscript -S --vanilla
```

which allows me to ./script.R and run it after a chmod as well.
This exact crontab commands also worked for me on my other laptops ubtunu vm, which is causing more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The command for running Rscript should be

```
Rscript path/to/Rscript.R
```

Please test the command by running it in your terminal. Once it run perfectly fine then just take the whole command and put it in crontab.

Comment: What difference is that than just calling ./script.R if the first line of the R script invoked Rscript from bin anyways? Also the cron still won't run